# nginx serve big images

Tags: nginx

There are some image on my page will be lost in safari, message in console `Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.`
images server be different domain, I can see the image properly by paste url in other browser tab.

I found this  https://gist.github.com/voronianski/791ef517c5392d7ce5fb but I don't know how to solve?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828576/unable-to-turn-off-chunked-transfer-encoding-in-nginx-with-gzip-for-static-asset

```
http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    open_file_cache max=102400 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;

    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 2;

    gzip  on;

    gzip_comp_level    5;
    gzip_min_length    256;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_vary          on;
....



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain  www.domain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;
    location /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/html/domain/app/robots.txt;
    }
    location ~ ^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts) {
        root /var/www/html/domain/app/assets;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
    location / {
        set $fixed_destination $http_destination;
        if ( $http_destination ~* ^https(.*)$ )
        {
            set $fixed_destination http$1;
        }
        proxy_pass http://127.00.0.1:8005/;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Destination $fixed_destination;

        client_max_body_size 50M;
        client_body_buffer_size 512k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
}
```

images server under sub.domain

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain  www.sub.domain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sub.domain.access.log;
    location /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/html/sub.domain/app/robots.txt;
    }
    location ~ ^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts) {
        root /var/www/html/sub.domain/app/assets;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
    location / {
        set $fixed_destination $http_destination;
        if ( $http_destination ~* ^https(.*)$ )
        {
            set $fixed_destination http$1;
        }
        proxy_pass http://127.00.0.1:8006/;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Destination $fixed_destination;

        client_max_body_size 50M;
        client_body_buffer_size 512k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I copy the image folder to under same domain for test but still get the same error, I stored images in different resolution so I test if I choose all smaller size and it work.  How to solve this? Do I miss something?   Should I increase the `keepalive_timeout` or anything?
I solve this by increase `send_timeout` from 2 to 60 it works get all images properly. is it ok to increase `send_timeout`, and right way solve this?